# Compare two UIImages

Tags: uiimage, compare

I have an application that will hold a set of images in a SQLDatabase and then the user will take a photo and I want to be able to match it with an image in the database.

I have no idea where to start, can anyone help? point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: I'm kinda trying to do almost the same, so... how did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by checking out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

The problem you are trying to solve is not exactly trivial though.  It is an area of ongoing research and none of the algorithms are perfect (in fact they're all far from perfect, IMO).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Start with OpenCV and understand that this is a non-trivial task.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Good luck.